# architecture suggestion for pure python two way multi threaded communication

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, discord.py, python-asyncio

my current environment is quite typical, but it seems surprisingly difficult to find quality recommendation for this scenario. There are no performance requirements, for ease of usage no additional software should be installed (no rabbitmq / zeromq etc)

There is one coordinator thread that receives/sends and sends data to all components:
0. "coordinator" event handler (in and out)

there are three components threads:

1. "UI" flask frontend (out)
2. mqtty subscirber / publisher (in and out)
3. discord.py (asyncio) (in and out)

for (0<--1&2&3) multiprocess queue is used, components put events to queue for coordinator
events = queue.Queue()

```
#coordinator
    while True:
    try:
        e = events.get()
        logging.info(f'event {e}')
        # .. do stuff .. #
    finally:
        events .task_done()

#any component
events.put_nowait('foobar')
```

for 0-->1 multiprocess manager is used, coordinator sets values for ui to display, this works fine.

```
manager = Manager()
ui_inp = manager.dict()

Thread(target=endpoint_frontend.run,
       args=(events, ui_inp),
       name='frontend',
       daemon=True).start()

#component
@app.route("/")
def status():
    foo = ui_inp['foo'].copy()
    return jsonify(foo)
```

for 0-->2 multiprocess queue is used, coordinator sets values, seems fine

```
mqtt_inp = queue.Queue()

Thread(target=endpoints_mqtt.run,
       args=(events, mqtt_inp),
       name='mqtt',
       daemon=True).start()

#component:
while Connected:
    try:
        event = input_queue.get()
        logging.warn(f"mqtt event {event}")
    finally:
        input_queue.task_done()
```

for 0-->3 asyncio queue is used, this is terrible asyncio.Queue is not thread safe.

```
discord_input = asyncio.Queue()

Thread(target=endpoint_discord.run,
       args=(events,discord_input),
       name='bot',
       daemon=True).start()

# component, discord class with one Cog
class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @tasks.loop(seconds=0.1)
    async def events(self):
        while not self.bot.is_closed():
            try:
                event = await self.bot.input_queue.get()
            finally:
                self.bot.input_queue.task_done()
```

Could You please recommend common clean pythonic way to handle this kind of coordinator to components communication?